# Playing sound from data acquired from Sound.extract()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to play a sound using a technique found [here](http://www.kaourantin.net/2008/05/adobe-is-making-some-noise-part-3.html) (play the sound by sampling raw sound data gathered from the original with extract()), with the difference that the mp3 sound is embedded in the swf, not loaded externally. This is my code:

```
var soundBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var mp3sound:Sound = Sound(new Sound1_design());  // this is the embedded sound
mp3sound.extract(soundBytes, int.MAX_VALUE);

soundBytes.position = 0;

var rawSound:Sound = new Sound();
rawSound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler);
rawSound.play();

function playbackSampleHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
     for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192 && soundBytes.bytesAvailable > 0; i++) 
     {
        var left:Number = soundBytes.readFloat();
        var right:Number = soundBytes.readFloat();
        event.data.writeFloat(left);
        event.data.writeFloat(right);
     }
}
```

This works, in a way, except that the resulting sound is distorted (it has a kind of a metallic ring). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could this be related to global sound quality settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried compiling it through mxmlc and through Flash CS5 and it's working great. I've tested it using a 128kbps and a 320kbps mp3 in my `[Embed(source="..")]`.

It's likely some other setting that's affecting the sound output, but it's hard to tell. Are you using a very low frame rate in your SWF? Maybe some Flash Player setting is strange like Lotus mentioned in his comment.

Comment: You've solved it (but maybe inadvertently :) ). Crucial thing here is `[Embed(source="..")]`. I wasn't using `[Embed`, instead I was importing sounds by importing them to a .fla first, then "compiling" the .fla into a .swc file, and then adding that .swc into Library in FlashDevelop (because I had a bunch of other symbols I needed to import from .fla anyway). For some reason (probably another flash bug), this makes all sounds a little distorted. But, with using `[Embed` it work flawlessly (as it does for you). Thanks!